# How can i echo alternate message depending on items within a php foreach loop

Tags: php, magento, foreach, echo

I am trying to display shipping prices on a product page in Magento. I have managed to do this by using php to echo the shipping prices. However, i am now offering free shipping on certain items and on these products i am getting the free shipping price echoed and another shipping price which looks wrong.

How can echo only free shipping when a product has it, and for everything else echo the normal price?

I have managed to just echo out the free shipping rule by using the following code:

```
        <?php
        if($_product->isSaleable())
        {
        $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId('*');
        $quote->addProduct($_product);
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals();
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();
        $rates = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRatesCollection();

        foreach ($rates as $rate)
        if ($rate->getPrice(0.00)) 
        {
            echo ('This item qualifies for FREE shipping');
        }
        else    
            echo ('Shipping from £' . $rate->getPrice());
        }
        ?>
```

But this still displays the other shipping price. How can i stop the other price displaying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have more than one rate to assess and you loop through them with a `foreach` you are going to get a message for each rate. Straightforward programming is needed.

```
$minPrice = PHP_INT_MAX;
foreach ($rates as $rate) {
    $minPrice = min($minPrice, $rate->getPrice());
}
if ($minPrice == 0) {
    echo ('This item qualifies for FREE shipping');
}
elseif ($minPrice < PHP_INT_MAX) {
    echo ('Shipping from £' . $rate->getPrice());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you don't mean to do:

```
if ($rate->getPrice()==0)
```

Because I don't believe you want to pass a value to a get method in Magento.